# Sparql Select query with condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sparql

Im doing an sparql query , I need to know how to put a condition in the where clause , suppose it returns M(Male) , F ( Female) , i want to bind the letter (M) to the word Male,(F) with Female.

Im new in sparql , i use sql and i need to find something like this in sparql:

```
Case when Gender  = 'M' then 'Male' when Gender = 'Female' then 'Female'
```

My query simplified is more less this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?Gender count(distinct ?publication)
FROM href
WHERE {
  ?publication a href.
  ?publication href ?AuthorList.
  ?AuthorList?item ?Person.
  ?Person foaf:gender ?genero   //Need here the condition
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i get it with this code:

```
SELECT ?Sexo count(distinct ?publication) 
FROM href
WHERE {
  ?publication a  href.
  ?publication < href ?listaAutores.
  ?listaAutores ?item ?persona.
  ?persona foaf:gender ?gender
  BIND(
    IF(contains(?gender, "f"), "Female",
    
    "Male")
    AS ?Sexo).
   
}
```